# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, login, php5

I have a issue with my PHP code. I'm trying to create a login system however when I execute the login i get this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/ASSETS/PHP/functions.php on line 15
```

Can anybody help?

My functions.php file

```
?php 

  function email_exists($email, $con) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function username_exists($username, $con) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function logged_in() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


?>
```

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Why are you asking the same off-topic question again? You already asked [Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/ASSETS/PHP/functions.php on line 15](https://superuser.com/q/1112886). Please take some time to read the [help] and understand how Stack Exchange works.